# awk grouping and sum of lists values

Tags: awk, grouping

Question on awk (bash) to sum values per item.  Input file looks like:

```
    item      value
    ----------------
    item1     8
    item1     1
    item1     5
    item2     2
    item2     8
    item3     4
    item3     7
    item3     7
    Timely Total    xxx

    item1   5  
    item1   4 
    item1   3
    item2   4
    item2   1
    Timely Total   17
```

My question:
To have sum per item, I have code:

```
 awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a) print i, "has", a[i], "entries" }'
```

That's fine, but it sums the whole file for all item1's in all Timelytotals

I need: sum of item1 in Timely total1, sum of item2 in Timely total1, sum of item3 in Timely total1, and then 
sum of item1 in Timely total2, sum of item2 in Timely total2, sum of item3 in Timely total2.
Similar for more Timely totals .

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the desired output for the given input data.  There are lots of ways you could be seeking to generate the data.  Your first 'timely total' line doesn't have a sum computed; should the code be doing that too?

Comment: When someone answers your question, you should not invalidate their answer by editing your question to something more complex.  You should ask the question you want answered in the first place.  Consider asking a second question if you need a different scenario dealt with.  Failing that — for example, you find that there's something else to deal with — you edit the question to leave the original sufficiently intact that the answers make sense.  Your revision seems to show the desired output but not the input.  Or, if it shows the input, it is not clear what the desired output is.  Not good!

Comment: I've rolled back to the cleaned-up version of the original question — it isn't ideal, but it is the problem that the answers tried to solve.  You should be able to adapt the ideas from the answers to your 'more complex situation'.  I think that if you can't, you should ask a new question — but, if you do so, make sure you show the input file and the desired output for that input file (and it would be a good idea to explain what the conceptual bottleneck is because it is a straight-forward process AFAICT).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not really stated what the output should look like, so any answer is to some extent a guess.  Here's my guess.

#### `script.awk`

```
NR < 3 { print; next }
$1 == "Timely" {
    for (a in sum)
    {
        print "Subtotal", a, sum[a]
    }
    print "Timely Total ", total
    total = 0;
    delete sum
    next
}
$1 == "" { print; next }
{
    sum[$1] += $2
    total += $2
    print
}
```

The first line prints the two heading lines unchanged.

The 'Timely' block prints the accumulated data (assuming that there is some to print).  For each item that showed up, it prints the corresponding sum, along with identification information.  It then prints a 'Timely Total' for the entire block. Then it zeroes out the statistics by deleting the `sum` array and zeroing `total`, ready for the next set of data.

The `$1 == ""` block prints but otherwise ignores blank lines.

The default block accumulates the sum for the item and the total and prints the line.

Clearly, if you don't want the individual data lines, then you omit the last `print`.  Equally clearly, you can print the subtotals (and indeed total) in any format you like — the `printf` function may well be useful here.  If you don't print the individual lines, you probably skip the two heading lines instead of printing them.  There are endless tweaks that could be made, but in the absence of contrary information, I believe this presents a reasonable answer that can readily be adapted to the desired output format.

One point to be aware of: the sample data ended up with the item subtotals printed in order, but that was most probably by chance rather than guaranteed behaviour. There are ways to fix that if it matters. However, there are multiple ways to do it, and GNU Awk has extra functions built in that help where other Awk variants require 'hand coding'.

#### Sample output

```
$ awk -f script.awk data
item      value
----------------
item1     8
item1     1
item1     5
item2     2
item2     8
item3     4
item3     7
item3     7
Subtotal item1 14
Subtotal item2 10
Subtotal item3 18
Timely Total  42

item1   5  
item1   4 
item1   3
item2   4
item2   1
Subtotal item1 12
Subtotal item2 5
Timely Total  17
$
```

Comment: thank you Jonathan that output was indeed what i was looking for .     cheers  Luc

Comment: 1) A little remark :  in ksh  (on aix)  i use set -A arrayname instead of delete (not known in ksh) . you could not know tha platform - sorry .                                      2) a question :

Comment: @hualpa: Since it is an Awk script that uses the `delete`, not a shell script of any sort, I don't see the relevance of your `set -A arrayname` comment.  The file labelled `script.awk` is indeed a file — though you could write its contents as a direct argument to `awk` inside single quotes if you wanted to — and is interpreted solely by `awk` and not by any shell.

Comment: hallo Jonathan, I updated the question :  2 columns to be summarized.  I updated the input and result file samples.   Can you help me on this "more tricky one " please ?   Thank you     Luc

Comment: @hualpa: Succinctly — no.  See my comments to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on a detailed question, and explaining what you're trying to accomplish. One approach is to use something other than $1 as the key to the associative array.  Since there's nothing in the total field that looks like a key, you can just keep a counter for how many times you've seen "Timely" before and increment it for each one.

```
$awk 'BEGIN {timely=1;} /^item[0-9]+/ {a[timely "-" $1]+=$2} /^Timely.*/ {timely+=1} END {for(i in a) print i,"has" ,a[i] " entries" }' < t | sort
1-item1 has 14 entries
1-item2 has 10 entries
1-item3 has 18 entries
2-item1 has 12 entries
2-item2 has 5 entries
```

The key part is `a[timely "-" $1]+=$2` which stores the totals in separate "buckets" every time a new `/^Timely.*/` is found.